# How to remove spacing around SearchBar control on iOS in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a SearchBar control in Xamarin forms which displays like this in iOS:

```xml
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Margin="20,20">

        <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="20" TextColor="White">Page Title</Label>

        <SearchBar Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   Placeholder="Search"
                   PlaceholderColor="White"
                   TextColor="White"
                   ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal">
        </SearchBar>

        <Label BackgroundColor="Gray" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White">
            Full Width Content
        </Label>

    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I would like to get rid of the extra padding (empty space) on the left and on the right of the search box so that the box fills the entire width of the StackLayout, just like the element under it:

[image: Preview]

How can I achieve it?

Setting `Margin=0` does not help, setting `ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal"` does not help, there is no padding property on this element.

The only thing that seems to work is `Margin="-8"` but I don't like negative margins as they seem hackish to me:

```xml
<SearchBar Margin="-8"
           Placeholder="Search"
           PlaceholderColor="White"
           TextColor="White"
           ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal">
</SearchBar>
```

[image: Margin -8]

Comment: Looks there is no property to do from XAML. You can try to use renderer and check.

Comment: @adamsfamily UISearchBar have this property `searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment:UIOffset` which you can set to UIOffset(-8,0) in custom render to remove left and right space for searchbar.